# how to change color of rectangle every 5 seconds in js

Tags: javascript, html

this code change the color of the rectangle so fast. How can I change it so that the color will change every 5 seconds?

```
var bgcolorlist=new Array("#DFDFFF", "#FFFFBF", "#80FF80", "#EAEAFF", "#C9FFA8", "#F7F7F7", "#FFFFFF", "#DDDD00")
POP.Draw.rect(0, 0, POP.WIDTH, POP.HEIGHT, bgcolorlist[Math.floor(Math.random()*bgcolorlist.length)]);
```

Comment: Where is that code called from? (The code shown would change the colour exactly once, which isn't what you seem to be saying when you talk about it changing "fast".)

Comment: I guess the code is being called from the continuously updating function.

Answer (score 0):

```
Please try this 

var bgcolorlist=new Array("#DFDFFF", "#FFFFBF", "#80FF80", "#EAEAFF","#C9FFA8", "#F7F7F7", "#FFFFFF",     "#DDDD00")
function draw(){
var canvas = document.getElementById('a');
var context = canvas.getContext('2d');
context.beginPath();
context.rect(20,20, 100, 100);
context.fillStyle =bgcolorlist[Math.floor(Math.random()*bgcolorlist.length)];
context.fill();
context.lineWidth = 7;
}
draw();
setInterval(function(){
draw();
},5000);
```

Comment: it only turns to white

Answer (score 0):

setInterval(function(){
object.style.backgroundColor=bgcolorlist[Math.floor(Math.random()*bgcolorlist.length)];
},5000);